# Getting Line Number of Location in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Say I have an NSString and a location in the string.

```
NSString *string = @"Hello\nHi\nOK\n";
int location = 6; //Should represent the letter H in "Hi"
int lineNumber = // Get line number of the character at location 6
NSLog(@"Line Number: %i",lineNumber); // 1
```

What do I do to get the line number of that string, which in the example above should be line 1?

I tried using `lineRangeByRange:` but that only gives me two additional locations in the string: the start of the line and the end of the line.

EDIT: While awaiting answers, I thought about it and tried this:

```
__block int lineNumber = 0;
__block int locationNumber = 0;
[string enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString * line, BOOL * stop){
    if(affectedCharRange.location > locationNumber + line.length){
        int lineLength = line.length;
        locationNumber += line.length + 1; // Added 1 to line.length to account for newline character that was not included in line
        lineNumber++;
    }else{
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
NSLog(@"Line Number: %i",lineNumber);
```

This worked when I tried it, but I'm not sure that it will always work. Will this work with other types of newline characters?

Comment: how you can recognised  how many lines are there  ?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the substring preceding your target character location and count the number of newlines in that substring:

```
let s = "Hello\nHi\nOK\n" as NSString
let loc = 6
let before = s.substringToIndex(loc)
let whatLine = before.componentsSeparatedByString("\n").count - 1 // 1, the desired answer
```

Comment: Sometimes the lines will be separated by the `\r` character, so this won't always work. I think these are from text files that were edited on Windows machines. And yes, the first line is line 0.

Comment: "Sometimes the lines will be separated by the \r character, so this won't always work" Oh come on. You're not even trying! Just call `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` and supply the characters that it might be. Don't keep moving the goalposts and expecting others to rush around and do your work for you; do some thinking for yourself. Or at least do some searching; this is a well-solved class of problem.

Comment: Sorry... it's late and I wasn't thinking... But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello\nHi\nOK\n";
NSString *stringWithoutBreaks = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
int location = 6;
NSString *theCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [stringWithoutBreaks characterAtIndex:location - 1]];
NSLog(@"theCharacter: %@", theCharacter); // H
```

Comment: I'm looking for Line Number. I already know the location of H.

Comment: Sorry about that. You updated your example while I was trying my answer.